# Vert.x, Clojure and Leiningen

Tags: clojure, vert.x

Vert.x modules have a gradle structure, and I'm not sure how to fit my clojure files into it.  Do they go into the resources directory, or should I create a separate directory under main called "clojure"?

Second, should I maintain the leiningen structure within the module?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If support for compiling Clojure source is configured, Vert.x will compile any source file found under the `resources/` folder. See [the code at https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-clojure](https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-clojure), and [its documentation](http://vertx.io/core_manual_clojure.html).

---

If you want to use a different toolchain (IDE, etc), you will need to tell vert.x where the class files and dependencies are found. Within the Gradle or Maven project template this is done via the `vertx_classpath.txt` file. So you could create a `clojure` folder under 'main' and organize your code as you like there. To let vert.x find and deploy the code you will have to tell the IDE or build tool where to put compiled class files etc. and vert.x via `vertx_classpath.txt` where to find them.

---

As yet another option, [a Leiningen module is available](https://github.com/isaiah/lein-vertx). Usage is typical:

```
lein new vertx yourproject
cd yourproject
lein vertx run
```

Comment: Better formatting might be helpful, but this is a great answer! (Would you mind if I took a shot at said formatting?)